# Platform independent replacement for LuaInterface

Tags: xna, lua, monogame

I'm currently working on a project in C#/XNA, however I'm planning to migrate this to MonoGame so that it can go onto more platforms. The problem is that I am currently using a lot of Lua, and for that in XNA, I am using LuaInterface.

The issue I now have is that LuaInterface only runs on Windows because of the dlls that it requires, but I would like to make this project available on Linux and Macs as well. Does anyone know of a good alternative to LuaInterface that could slot into Mono quite nicely?

Re-writing the parts which are currently in Lua in another language wouldn't be too much of a problem, but I need to be able to use scripting as I want to make large portions of my game open to players for modding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use KopiLua, which is a Lua interpreter rewritten entirely in plain C#.

KopiLua and LuaInterface can work together and in fact someone did, calling it KopiLuaInterface. Just google that.

Update: For those reading this answer, there have been two other projects that do the same which might be worth looking into as well: [NLua](https://github.com/NLua/NLua) and [Moonsharp](https://github.com/xanathar/moonsharp/)